# Página não recebe e não cadastra os dados no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou montando uma aplicação em php para registro de usuários, mas por algum motivo quando insiro os dados e clico em registrar, ele recarrega a página não dá nenhum erro, e não carrega nada no banco.

```
    <?php
    $page_title = 'Registra Usuario';
    include ('includes/header.html');

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
        require_once ('includes/conexao.php');

        $erros = array();

        if (empty($_POST['p_nome'])) {
            $empty[] = 'Você esqueceu de digitar seu primeiro nome.';
        } else {
            $un = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['p_nome']));
        }

        if (empty($_POST['u_nome'])) {
            $empty[] = 'Você esqueceu de digitar seu ultimo nome.';
        } else {
            $pn = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['u_nome']));
        }

        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
            $empty[] = 'Você esqueceu de digitar seu email.';
        } else {
            $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['email']));
        }

        if (!empty ($_POST['pass1'])) {
            if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
                $erros[] = 'Seu password não corresponde a confirmação.';
            } else {
                $p =   $un = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['pass1']));
            }
        } else {
            $erros[] = 'Você esqueceu de digitar seu password.';
        }

        if (empty($erros)) {
            $q = "INSERT INTO usuario (p_nome, u_nome, email, pass, data_reg) VALUES ('$pn', '$un', '$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW())";

            $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            if ($r){
                echo '<h1> Obrigado!</h1>
                <p> Agora você está registrado</p>
                <p><br /></p>';
            } else {
                echo '<h1> Erro no Sistema </h1>
                      <p class=""error"> você não pôde ser registrado devido a um erro do sistema.
                      Pedimos desculpa por qualquer inconveniente</p> ';
                echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc).
                     '<br /> <br/> Query: ' . $q . '</p>';    
            }
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            include('includes/footer.html');
            exit();
        } else {
            echo '<h1>Erro!</h1> <p class="error">Ocorreram os seguinte(s)erro(s): <br /> ';

            foreach ($erros as $msg ){
                echo " - $msg<br />\n";
            }
            echo '</p><p> Por favor, tente novamente. </p><p><br /></p>';
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
    ?>

  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#teste").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.info($("#myform").serialize());
            console.info($("#teste").val())
        });
    });

</script>

        <h1> Registrar Usúario</h1>
        <form action="registro.php" method="post" id="myform">
            <p> Primeiro Nome: <input type="text" name="p_nome" size="15" maxlength="20"
            value="<?php if (isset($_POST['p_nome'])) echo trim ($_POST['p_nome']); ?>" /> </p>

            <p> Último Nome: <input type="text" name="u_nome" size="15" maxlength="40"
            value="<?php if (isset($_POST['u_nome'])) echo trim ($_POST['u_nome']); ?>" /> </p>

            <p> Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="15" maxlength="80"
            value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo trim ($_POST['email']); ?>" /> </p>

            <p>Senha: <input type="password" name="pass1" size="10" maxlength="20" /> </p>
            <p>Confirmação de Senha: <input type="password" name="pass2" size="10" maxlength="20" /> </p>

            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrar" id="teste" /></p>

            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
        </form>
```

Adicionei esse código jquery para ver se eles estava passando os valores e o resultado foi :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: só pra constar, tem aspas a mais aqui: `<p class=""error">` - Uma coisa que você tem que tomar cuidado, é não mostrar nem a query nem os erros pro usuário final. O ideal é gravar num log e apenas avisar que a aplicação teve um problema inesperado.

Comment: Caso haja erro com a query, o [@](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) vai fazer com que eles sejam ignorados. A linha `$p =   $un = mysqli_ [...];` é realmente o que você quer?

Comment: @Berriel sim é o que quero

Comment: @Bacco a intenção é mostrar mesmo, mas valeu pelas dicas.

Comment: @GuilhermeLima tem certeza que você quer que o `$un`, que deve ser o `username`, seja igual ao `pass1`?

Comment: @Barriel foi um erro de digitação era pra ser somente $p

Answer (score 0):

Cara verifica se a conexão esta aberta no arquivo, tente executar o comando SELECT NOW() deve apresentar a data e hora, se não der, da um echo da query ($q) e tenta executar direto no seu banco de dados se nao der nenhum erro informe novamente

Comment: coloquei o now() embaixo do mysqli_close($dbc); ele nao apresenta a hora..

Answer (score 0):

Se não apresenta erros é por que a sua query não esta sendo executada.
Faça um query de insert manual e veja se algum erro é retornado com mysli_error.